# Why is my computer connecting to several instances of compute.amazon.com?

Tags: windows, firefox, amazon-web-services

When faffing about with Sysinternals TCPview, I noticed that Firefox was connecting to several instances of compute.amazon.com.

[image: TCPView screenshot]

While browsing various sites, these connections would appear and disappear in chunks.  But, I could never get them to completely go away.  The only pages that were constantly open were Cookie Clicker and DuckDuckGo.  Is this just due to several sites using Amazon cloud instances?  Or am I actually part of some kind of botnet?  This is probably nothing, but it's strange to see all of those connections appear and disappear like that.

Comment: @heavyd - Clearly I looked at the picture since I indicate the connections in the TIME-WAIt condition but missed those other connections.

Comment: Did you run `sfc.exe` yourself?

Comment: No. but I'm not sure what was running in the background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connections you are seeing from Firefox are connections to DuckDuckGo, which uses Amazon EC2 for its hosting.

The hostnames you show actually reveal the IP addresses they point to (`50.18.192.250` and `50.18.200.106`).  If you put those into your browser, it opens DuckDuckGo.

Comment: Haha, it's funny.  I did a whois lookup on all of the IPs, but not once did I think to just put one in the address bar.  Do you have an idea on the 54.221.166.68 address?